# Http Session - Implementation class

Tags: java

I have a doubt regarding the implementation of HTTPSession interface - javax.servlet.http

That is, where I can find the actual implementation of Http Session?

My purpose is I need to modify the implementation of HTTPSession.getID function which provides the unique session id for each session to suit my needs.

For that, I need to understand how getID function is implemented

Comment: How will you modify those javax.servlet.http API's ?

Comment: Do you doubt on that method? Just curious, why do you need to customize it?

Comment: In some Forums, it is said that the servlet container mightn't provide unique Session IDs , for ex: When you restart the server. I would add the timestamp + machine ip to the session id to make it unique always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is provided by your servlet container. Why do you want to have specific session IDs? Most probably there is an easier way to solve your underlying problem than influencing the session ID by messing up with the implementation of the Servlet API.

Comment: In some Forums, it is said that the servlet container mightn't provide unique Session IDs , for ex: When you restart the server.

I would add the timestamp + machine ip to the session id to make it unique always

Comment: If you want to persist data between restarts of your servlet container, you should use a database, and save important data there.

Comment: But isnt it better to know how the session id is assigned uniquely using the getID?

where can i see the source code for the servlet container?

Comment: I saw one sample servlet container

It just extends HttpServlet right??

Comment: No, that is a _servlet_ which runs inside a servlet container (e.g. Apache Tomcat).